# Compare values in two tables and update table1 if table2 has a higher value

Tags: sql, mysql

I'd like help with a mysql query that:

- For the `max(id)` for each transaction.position rows where `t_type = 'buy'`
- Gets the most recent (by date) price from the `quotes2010` table (based on the `transactions.symbol`)
- IF the price for the symbol is higher than the price in the `transactions.high` column
- Subtract 0.01 from the higher `quotes2010.price`
- Update the higher price in the `transactions.high` column

. . . . in a single query.

The most basic thing I'm trying to do is UPDATE the a table IF the price for the symbol in the 2nd table is higher. Here is a basic version of the database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transactions` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `symbol` char(8) NOT NULL,
  `high` double(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `t_type` enum('buy','sell') NOT NULL,
  `t_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `position` (`position`,`id`),
  KEY `t_date` (`t_date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `transactions` VALUES(1, 'AO1', 1.35, '2010-12-12 00:08:57');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `quotes2010` (
  `symbol` char(8) NOT NULL,
  `price` double(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`symbol`,`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `quotes2010` VALUES('A01', 1.40, '2010-12-19 10:03:05');
```

Comment: Column "position" is missing from table and insert statement.

Comment: Your CREATE TABLE dump is in correct -- there is no position field on transactions.  Also, please provide test data that is more representative to test the desired constraints.

Comment: You are both correct. I am new here, and I was just trying to strip down the table structure (in an attempt to be more clear). In the future, I'll do better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema and dataset are limited, but I think this will do what you need.

```
UPDATE 
quotes2010 INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT symbol, MAX(date) AS max_date
    FROM quotes2010
    GROUP BY symbol
) quote_by_maxdate ON quote_by_maxdate.symbol=quotes2010.symbol AND quote_by_maxdate.max_date=quotes2010.date
INNER JOIN transactions ON quotes2010.symbol = transactions.symbol
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT symbol, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM transactions
    WHERE t_type='buy'
    GROUP BY symbol
) transactions_by_max_id ON transactions.id=transactions_by_max_id.max_id 
SET quotes2010.price = IF(quotes2010.price > transactions.high,quotes2010.price-0.01,quotes2010.price),
transactions.high = IF(quotes2010.price > transactions.high,quotes2010.price,transactions.high)
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! This answer worked great! I simply had to remove the line that udpated the quotes2010 table (because I never want to update that table).  I need to modify the high price (in a somewhat complex way) before it is updated with another query. I have a working query already, I just don't know how to integrate it  into the successful query above. Should I make another question for that, or append it here?

Comment: Awesome. Depends how related the other qestions are I suppose. If you can't integrate it into this one, then a new one makes sense IMO.